# Influence of delta potential (particle in a box)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, potential, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions

I have a question about the problem with a particle in a box and an additional delta potential:

$V(x)=g\delta(x)+V_B(x)$

with $V_B(x)=0$ for $|x|\leq L$ and $V_B(x)=\infty$ elsewhere.

From this I want to determine the wave functions of the ground state and the first excited state in the whole space with $g<\infty$.

Now, my ideas. The normal approach for a particle in a box is:

$\Psi(x)=A\cos(kx)+B\sin(kx)$,

or, equivalently, $\Psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}$,

with the boundary conditions

$\Psi(\pm L)=0$.

This approach is used in the Schrödinger equation to determine the energy eigenvalues.

Furthermore, I know this condition for delta potentials (from integrating the Schrödinger equation):

$\Psi'(0^+)-\Psi'(0^-)=\frac{2m}{\hbar^2}g\Psi(0)$

My problem is, how does the delta potential change the problem, so how do you proceed in this case?

Please note: I do not require a complete solution for some homework, or anything of that kind. I would just like to know, how the delta potential changes matters, and which Ansatz for the wave function is used here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If one puts a delta-function spike inside an infinite square well, is the resulting potential analytically solvable?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/465178/)

Comment: Thanks for that link! Unfortunately, I don't quite understand where the wavefunction Ansatz, which is used there, comes from...
The calculations afterwards are not my problem.

Comment: Well, in the region between the delta functions and the walls the particle is "free" right? And at the points $x=0$ and $x=L$ the solution should go to zero. As a result, the ansatz is pretty straightforward, I think... You could rigorously try to solve this in both regions separately and you'd end up with the same answer, I think.

Comment: You're right, that makes sense! One issue, though: We are assuming a finite $g$ here, i.e. a permeable wall. 
What do the wave functions "look like" compared to the case of $g=\infty$?